# Does "aws_vpn_gateway" resource have an ability to set timeout for create and remove?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-template-file

I have an aws to azure connection(cfg file which I running in the test).

The problem is that sometimes the tests are failing because of aws_vpn_gateway is not being Removed(teardown step).

Please note that it is flakey behaviour, sometimes it passes sometimes it failing, so I think there is some default time for removing it(for example 5 mins).
But due to some delays in the system, sometimes it takes 6 mins to remove it, so it's failing.

Here is the resource description.

```
    resource "aws_vpn_gateway" "nightly_tests_aws_vpn_gateway_1" {
      vpc_id = aws_vpc.nightly_tests_aws_vpc_1.id
      tags = {
      nefeli_managed = "true"
      }
    }
```

The question is, is there any timeout block or other way to increase remove time for  aws_vpn_gateway resource?

For example Azure has such block for resource.

```
    timeouts {
     create = "2h0m0s"
     update = "2h0m0s"
     delete = "2h0m0s"
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately [aws_vpn_gateway](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/vpn_gateway.html) resource doesn't support timeouts nested block. More info about timeout operations see: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/syntax#operation-timeouts.